# Typo3 - Add a filter to solr search in typo3

Tags: typo3

How to add filters in typo3 with Solr search extension ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might better ask in the official Mailinglist/Newsgroup, as Ingo, Olivier and other TYPO3 Solr experts are answering your questions there:

- Mailing list http://lists.typo3.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/typo3-project-solr
- Newsgroup news://lists.typo3.org/typo3-project-solr

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get any answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure people find a proper answer here as well. This can be done via TypoScript configuration. The related configuration parts are documented in the project wiki: http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-solr/wiki/Tx_solrsearch#faceting

Answer (score 0):

```
plugin.tx_solr.search.query {
    filter {
        pagesOnlyFilter = type:pages
    }
}
```

That's how you can do it via Setup-TS in the current Solr EAP Version. Don't know if it works for you though, because you didn't post details about the Version that you use.